# How to create a new resource in Azure ARM templates?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Ok, I've done everything what described here with ARM template - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet. Except one thing - Enabling VNET Integration with a pre-existing VNET.

Can this be done in ARM templates?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you share you template, so that I don't have to start over?

Comment: I wish I could, but this is for a client and moreover it's big with lots of params and variables.Sorry, can't do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a sample template that might help you. It's modified from [this quickstart sample in GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-web-app-python)

```
{
   "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
   "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
   "parameters": {
      "hostingPlanName": {
         "type": "string",
         "minLength": 1,
         "metadata": {
            "description": "Name of the hosting plan to use in Azure."
         }
      },
      "webSiteName": {
         "type": "string",
         "minLength": 1,
         "metadata": {
            "description": "Name of the Azure Web app to create."
         }
      },
      "vnetName": {
         "type": "string",
         "minLength": 1,
         "metadata": {
            "description": "Name of an existing Azure VNet which has a Gateway Subnet already, and is in the resource group you are going to deploy."
         }
      },
      "skuName": {
         "type": "string",
         "defaultValue": "S1",
         "allowedValues": [
            "S1",
            "S2",
            "S3",
            "P1",
            "P2",
            "P3",
            "P4"
         ],
         "metadata": {
            "description": "Describes plan's pricing tier and instance size. Check details at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/"
         }
      },
      "skuCapacity": {
         "type": "int",
         "defaultValue": 1,
         "minValue": 1,
         "metadata": {
            "description": "Describes plan's instance count"
         }
      }
   },
   "resources": [
      {
         "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
         "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
         "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
         "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
         "tags": {
            "displayName": "HostingPlan"
         },
         "sku": {
            "name": "[parameters('skuName')]",
            "capacity": "[parameters('skuCapacity')]"
         },
         "properties": {
            "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]"
         }
      },
      {
         "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
         "name": "[parameters('webSiteName')]",
         "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
         "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
         "tags": {
            "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "Resource",
            "displayName": "Website"
         },
         "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
         ],
         "properties": {
            "name": "[parameters('webSiteName')]",
            "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
         },
         "resources": [
            {
               "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
               "name": "web",
               "type": "config",
               "dependsOn": [
                  "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('webSiteName'))]"
               ],
               "properties": {
                  "pythonVersion": "3.4"
               }
            },
            {
              "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
              "name": "[parameters('vnetName')]",
              "type": "virtualNetworkConnections",
              "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
              "dependsOn": [
                  "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('webSiteName'))]"
              ],
              "properties": {
                  "vnetResourceId": "[concat(resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('vnetName'))]"
              }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Here are 3 things you should be careful with.

1. The template starts with a python web app template, and adds a "Microsoft.Web/sites/virtualNetworkConnections" resource. So, if you are using other programing language, you can start with some other template.
2. The pre-existing VNet should be in the same resource group you are deploying. If the VNet you are using are not in the same resource group, you should modify the "vnetResourceId" in the "properties" of the "Microsoft.Web/sites/virtualNetworkConnections".
3. The VNet you are using should have a Gateway with a Point-to-Site address already. Otherwise, you will not be able integrate you web app to the VNet. For more details, see [Configure a Point-to-Site connection to a virtual network using PowerShell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-rm-ps/)

**Update**: About how I get this info, well, there is not much about this on the net. This template is constructed based on the PowerShell solution and my knowledge about ARM template. The PowerShell solution is available in [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-vnet-integration-powershell). Another possible way to get an ARM template is to create those resources in one resource group, and export the template of the resource group in the portal. But, for this case, that is not going to work, because resource type "Microsoft.Web/sites/virtualNetworkConnections" is not supported yet. However, you can still get a look at the REST API by the PowerShell Command `Get-AzureRmResource` with option `-debug`.

```
Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName <resource group> -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/virtualNetworkConnections -Name <web app>/<VNet> -debug -ApiVersion 2015-08-01
```

You will get the following REST API.

Uri:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourceGroups/<resource group>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<web app>/virtualNetworkConnections/<VNet>?api-version=2015-08-01
```

Body:

```
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourceGroups/<resource group>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<web app>/virtualNetworkConnections/<VNet>",
  "name": "<VNet>",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/virtualNetworkConnections",
  "location": "<Location>",
  "tags": null,
  "properties": {
    "vnetResourceId": "/subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourceGroups/<resource group>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/<VNet>"
    "certThumbprint": "<Thumbprint>",
    "certBlob": "<cert>",
    "routes": null,
    "resyncRequired": false,
    "dnsServers": null
  }
}
```

Skipping some automatically generated values, you will get the template which is quite similar to the one I write:

```
{
  "name": "<VNet>",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/virtualNetworkConnections",
  "location": "<Location>",
  "properties": {
    "vnetResourceId": "/subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourceGroups/<resource group>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/<VNet>"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining how did you get this info? resource explorer? where did you get this schema? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the update! I did not know about the trick with -debug ! Nice one!

Comment: This worked great for me too! Finding the resource via the resource explorer at https://resources.azure.com was a better way for me to find the json template though. 

From Providers, I drilled down to: Microsoft.Web/sites/<sitename>/virtualNetworkConnections to get the network resource to create

Comment: I have tried this template, but if I deploy the template, the vNet is added, but the portal tells me the certificates are not in sync (and the vNet does not work). I tried adding the certThumbprint and certBlob parameters, but I still have the same problem. If I check the resource explorer, I can see the certBlob is correctly set, but the thumbprint is not. Do you have an idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: Same here. Azure Support sais they're working on it (some kind of issue)

Comment: Same issue here - after deploying VNET connection I shall do manual VNET sync :( (almost a year passed)

Comment: Still not fixed. Has anyone got an open support ticket / GitHub issues reference for this 'certificates-not-in-sync' issue?

Comment: Syncing the certificates can't be done using ARM. You must use Powershell to do this : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/53d19f76-2d2d-40e8-856f-44d31e80e7d4/arm-deploy-app-service-to-vnet-doesnt-sync-certifcates?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork